# differentiating a Summation for the mean energy - Statistical Physics

Tags: statistics, derivatives, summation, physics

I am currently taking a Physics course Statistical Physics, and this pop up regularly:

[this is from Fundamental of statistical and thermal physics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaPdB.png)

My question is: I understand Z is the partition theorem equal to the summation from zero to infinity of exponential to the - beta times the energy.
How is the derivative related to the summation?
why can I go from the left side of the equation meaning the side where both summations are present to the right side where theres a partial derivative of z with respect to beta.

what is the math process to go from summations to derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

In physics, $Z$ is the partition function given by
$$Z = \sum_{i}e^{-\beta E_i}$$ where i = 1,2,3.. $\infty$ is the index of the microstates of the system.

Now if you differentiate w.r.t. $\beta$, you get
$$\frac{\delta Z}{\delta \beta} = -E_i Z$$
This is true because the derivative of the sum is equal to sum of derivatives. And the derivative of each term in the summation is equal to $E_i e^{-\beta E_i}$, for a given microstate $i$.

$$ E_i = -\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\delta Z}{\delta \beta}$$

$\frac{1}{Z}$ can also be written as $\frac{\delta}{\delta \beta} ln Z$. Hence the relation. Hope this helps.